# Harmonic Functions With a Pole at the Origin

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Suppose that $u:\mathbb D \setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb R$ is harmonic and that $\lim_{z\to 0} u(z)=\infty$.
>
> Show that $u$ can be written as $$u(z)=\beta \ln |z| + v(z) $$ where $\beta\in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ and $v:\mathbb D \to \mathbb R $ is harmonic in $\mathbb D$ (Here $\mathbb D = \{|z|<1\} $).

I was also given the following hint:

> **Hint:** Show that the residue of $(u_x - i u_y) $ is real.

I believe that the solution sould be related to **Dirichlet's problem**, and especially to **[Poisson's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_unit_disc)**, but I don't understand how to use those to solve it.

Any help would will be appreciated!

Comment: On any simply connected open set $U\subset \{0<|z| < 1\}$, 

$u(z) = \Re(f(z))$ where $f$ is analytic on $U$, and the analytic continuation of $f$ is analytic over any curve $\subset \{0<|z| < 1\}$, and over closed curves, the continuation $f_\gamma$ differs off $f$ by a purely imaginary constant.

Let $A = \lim_{t \to 0} f(e^{2i \pi (1-t)})- f(e^{2i \pi t})$ which is purely imaginary.

Then $g(z)=f(z)- A \frac{\log z}{2i\pi}$ is analytic on $0 < |z| < 1$.

Comment: From there look at the 3 cases : $g$ has an essential singularity, a pole, a removable singularity, and show only in the latter case $\lim_{z \to 0} |u(z)| = \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Why can we use analytic continuation (for $f$)? Also I'd love an explantion for the definition of $A$ (we use $f(e^{2\pi i t})$, but $f$ is only defined on $U\subseteq \{0<|z|<1\}$....)

Comment: From the Poisson kernel you can construct $f$ analytic on $0<|z|<1, z \not \in (-1,0]$ such that $u(z) = \Re(f(z))$. The point is that moving the contour you used for the Poisson kernel shows $f$ can be continued analytically along every curve $\gamma \subset 0 < |z| < 1$ and that when continued analytically along the closed curve $\gamma : r e^{it}, t \in [0,2\pi]$ then $f\mapsto f_\gamma$ with $\Re(f_\gamma-f)=0$ thus $f_\gamma-f$ is constant $=A \in i \Bbb{R}$ and hence $f-\frac{A}{2i\pi} \log z$ is analytic on $0< |z|< 1$

Comment: Thanks for your explanations! This way it looks like the constant $A$ depends on the choice of the curve $\gamma$. But you used $A$ to define $g\in Hol(\{ 0<|z|<1 \})$. What am I missing here?